# How to fix this selection sort logical error?

Tags: python, list

i am trying to implement selection sort  but it doesn't pan  out the same way as said in algorithm did I do something wrong with assignment operators?

```py
def selection_sort(list_1):
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        val = min(list_1[i:])
        list_1[i],list_1[list_1.index(val)] =list_1[list_1.index(val)], list_1[i]
    print (list_1)

print(selection_sort([3,3,4,3,465,45,346,5,456,545,345345,345]))`
```

Comment: Post actual vs expected output

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because when you call the `index` function, there are multiple numbers in the array with the same value. Thus, it picks the first matching number it sees in the entire array, which may be an already sorted value (before current `i`).

This is a better way of doing it:

```py
def selection_sort(list_1):
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        min_val = list_1[i]
        min_i = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list_1)):
            if list_1[j] < min_val:
                min_val = list_1[j]
                min_i = j

        list_1[i], list_1[min_i] = list_1[min_i], list_1[i]
    print (list_1)

selection_sort([3,3,4,3,465,45,346,5,456,545,345345,345])
```

The new chunk of code finds the index of the smallest value past `i`, which is stored in `min_i`.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out that problem is caused by list_1.index(val), becuase each time it will search for val in the beginning of the list , for solving this problem it's enough to use second parameter like this list_1.index(val, start)

```
def selection_sort(list_1):
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        val = min(list_1[i:])
        temp = list_1[i]
        list_1[list_1.index(val, i)], list_1[i] = temp, val
    print (list_1)

selection_sort([3,3,4,3,465,45,346,5,456,346,456,545,345345,345])
```

result is [3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 45, 345, 346, 346, 456, 456, 465, 545, 345345]